# Force desktop site on tablet (Wordpress)

Tags: wordpress

I'm using Wordpress 5.9.2 and wanted to know if there is anyway I can do that when someone get into my site with tablet it will show him the desktop view?
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

This depends on your theme. And this theme most probably doesn't check if the website gets opened from tablet or desktop, but just checks the overall screensize and provides break points (for example for 800px screen width). Depending on your knowledge, you could edit your theme's style.css (or create child-theme) and edit the media queries there, maybe even just deleting the ones, responsible for the "tablet-size" breakpoint is enough.

If this is unfamiliar for you, as far as I know, there is no simple "deactivate tablet mode" button.